Mid/late 70s horror movie where group of people venture to a hidden valley and are attacked by a gargoyle
I have vague memories of a horror movie, where this group of people ventures through a cave or portal to a hidden valley maybe. 
I only remember the scene, probably towards the end where the sole survivor (possibly) escapes but is attacked by a flying devil/beats gargoyle, it lands on his/her back and claws at his her back. I vaguely remember that scene was done as stop motion, not just a puppet on her back.

It makes me think of Evil Dead 2. A group of people going to a small house in the woods, they go in the cave, find the evil Necronomicon, horror ensues. By the end, the only survivor is sent back in time, and attacked by a flying monster/gargoyle in stop motion.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Equinox, (1970):

Four friends are attacked by a demon while on a picnic, due to
  possession of a tome of mystic information. Told in flashbacks by the
  sole survivor.

This scene had the portal to a region where everything was tinted red.  This scene had the stop-motion demon, which gouged the back of its victim.  There is also a cameo by famed science fiction author Fritz Leiber.

woohoo I believe that's it!!!! thank you for that. That's a good demonstration of what people remember and forget, i will have to watch it now to bring back all those memories. It has all the elements I remember, the portal, cave, stop motion creature, but remember nothing about the book!

This sounds like At the Earth's Core from 1976.
Not to be confused with The Land That Time Forgot also starring Doug McClure.
In particular, there is a scene with flying reptiles or demons. See from 2 minutes into the trailer.

I don't think it was At Earth's Core... I don't remember it being a scifi movie i am thinking horror/evil. Not Evil Dead as that is too late, it has to be 70's, thankyou for thoughts anyway... still keenly searching

Gargoyles
 is the right time frame (70s), but I am not sure about the stop motion element, as I only remember an ocean of bad rubber monster suits for the gargoyles. 
